# How to do a proportional scaling of various TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a `ScrollView` with various different `TextView`. I have used sp as unit for text, however I cannot get a good visual result for all screen sizes.

I can only find the perfect textsize for a single sceen size, if I try to find a size too show a good result on different screen size, whatever sp size I try to use for the text is always too  small for a large display with too blank space, or too big  for smaller screens,

see this sample(too blank space on the right image (and large screens))
[image]

I have seen some implementations of AutoFit Twextview, but this  is not a good option since the different lenght of the various text lines cause every lines use a different text size with a bad aesthetic result.
I need a praticable way to scale proportionally all `TextView`

Comment: I guess you have to have different xml's for different screen sizes.

Comment: Why not create a different dimension for every screen type? In values folder (and other too values-*) create a dimens.xml file and use it in your textview with @dimens/name.... it's your problem?

Comment: I have this problem in many layouts with different TextView that requires different sizes(eg title is larger, suggestions are smaller etc), I don't knowif this solution ispraticable. try the best sizes for all screens and define different layouts requires too much time

Comment: u can create multilple values folder with styles for text and it'll not take ur much time.

Comment: could you give me a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Use style for textview - style as

```
 <style name="MyDefaultTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">    
 <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>     
<item name="android:textColor">#333</item>    
 <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>   
</style>
```

put it with same keys and different values in styles.xml in various values folder as u required.folder name such as `values` , `values-v11` , `values-sw600dp` etc and see results

Comment: could I style different TextView with different style? What is the difference between this approach and the use of `dimens.xml`?

Comment: yes u can definitely do this.you can follow this link for diff http://forums.devshed.com/android-development-165/android-dimens-xml-styles-xml-948389.html , as far i understand is that for style approach u need to add only style for set of properties with any view instead of specifying all type with dimen values.